# JavaScript Date object Windows vs Ubuntu

Tags: javascript

On the console in chrome browser of windows and Ubuntu I entered `Date()` object and I found both have a different way to write the timezone for that date.

Ubuntu:
"Thu Aug 10 2017 18:45:18 GMT+0530 (IST)"

Windows:
"Thu Aug 10 2017 18:45:18 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)"

According to my use case the output on Ubuntu is correct, the time zone IST is what expected. But on windows it always shows up India Standard Time.

Is there a way to fix this for windows.

Comment: This is either a superUser question, or another *well thats called browser war :/*

Comment: different browsers represent objects differently on their consoles. You are always free to format the date as you wish, like shown here https://stackoverflow.com/q/3552461/2557818

Answer (score 1):

> According to my use case the output on Ubuntu is correct

*Neither* of them is correct. Or incorrect. The string form of a `Date` from [`toString`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/index.html#sec-date.prototype.tostring) (which is what those appear to be) is **almost completely unspecified**. The only requirement is that it represent the date, and that `Date()` and `Date.parse` should be able to parse it.

If you want something reliable cross browser*, use [`toISOString`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/index.html#sec-date.prototype.toisostring).

---

* Obsolete browsers may not have `toISOString`. Even only vaguely-modern browsers do.